# error when calling function with 2 integer args

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm defining a function in PowerShell and trying to call it as shown below.

```
function foo([Int32] $a, [Int32] $b)
{
}
foo(0,0)
```

When I do this, I get the following error.

```
foo : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'a'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
 "System.Int32".
At line:1 char:4
+ foo <<<< (0,0)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [foo], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,foo
```

If I change the function to only accept a single argument as shown below it works fine.

```
function foo([Int32] $a)
{
}
foo(0)
```

Or, if I remove the type info it also works as shown below.

```
function foo($a, $b)
{
}
foo(0,0)
```

What's wrong with the first version?  How do I properly define a function which takes multiple integer arguments?

EDIT: Interestingly, the following invocation does work.

```
foo 0 0
```

I'd prefer the ()s though and am wondering how to get it to work with those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In powershell parameters are passed without parenthesis try:

```
foo 0 0
```

doing

foo(0,0)

you are passing an object array as first parameter.

You can pass the array and then split each value as parameter inside the script, but why do it?

Comment: ok thanks!  looks like I just need to switch gears from C++ and give up on the parenthesis :)

Comment: BTW this common gotcha is mentioned in the tag wiki (used to be called FAQ) - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function MyFunction ([int32]$arg1,[int32]$arg2)
 {


  $data= $arg1+$arg2 
 return $data 


 }
```

MyFunction 2 4

Comment: This one is vaild example to convert a arg as int32